# Solve : $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}\ln(n)^{n}}{\ln(n+1)^{n+1}x^{n}}$

Tags: limits

I need help with this limit.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}\ln(n)^{n}}{\ln(n+1)^{n+1}x^{n}}=(x)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(n)^{n}}{\ln(n+1)^{n}\ln(n+1)}$$
$$=(x)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)})^{n}\times \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$$

The problem is with this part of the limit.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg(\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\Bigg)^{n}$$

Can someone help?

Comment: Please, does $\ln (n)^n$ mean $(\ln n)^n$ or $\ln (n^n)$?

Comment: Based on the calculations the OP has done, it seems like it is:
$$(\ln{n})^n$$ This said, we should not make assumptions and resolving the ambiguity requires clarification from the OP.

Comment: $$1<\left(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln(n)}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac1{n\ln(n)}\right)^n<e^{1/\ln(n)}\to1$$

Comment: By the way, none of this is necessary, simply note that $$\left|\frac{x^{n+1}\ln(n)^{n}}{\ln(n+1)^{n+1}x^{n}}\right|\leqslant\frac{|x|}{\ln(n+1)}\to0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to evaluate the first part of that limit. It is always less than $1$, and the second limit tends towards $0$, so the whole thing tends towards $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $1$. To see it, let's show
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\biggl(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\biggr)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\biggl(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\biggr)=0.$$
We'll need an asymptotic expansion of the latter expression.
Now $$\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}= \frac{\ln n+\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)}{\ln n}=1+\frac 1{\ln n}\biggl(\frac1n+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)=1+\frac 1{n\ln n}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n\ln n}\Bigr)$$
so that
\begin{align}\ln\biggl(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\biggr)^n&=n\ln\biggl(1+\frac 1{n\ln n}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n\ln n}\Bigr)\biggr)=n\biggl(\frac 1{n\ln n}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n\ln n}\Bigr)\biggr)\\&=\frac 1{\ln n}+o\Bigl(\frac1{\ln n}\Bigr)\to 0.\end{align}
Therefor, the limit of the given expression is $0$.